# Error reading characters of string after wcscpy_s

Tags: c++, c, windows, wchar-t, wstring

I have a problem with the `wcscpy_s` function. After `wcscpy_s` returns the parameter (`stringOne`and `stringTwo`) of my function are not readable. 
Here is simple demo to show the problem.

```
void testFunc(LPCWSTR stringOne, LPCWSTR stringTwo) {

    wchar_t* defaultVal = L"Default";

    wchar_t tmp[100];

    int lenBefore = wcslen(stringOne); // Works

    auto result = wcscpy_s(tmp, sizeof(tmp), defaultVal);

    int len = wcslen(tmp);

    int len2 = wcslen(stringOne); // Throws Exception Access violation
}


int main() {
    testFunc(L"Test", L"Test");
}
```

Comment: One problem is that `sizeof(tmp)` gives you the size in *bytes*, but it should be the number of *elements* in the array. See e.g. [this `wcscpy_s` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentgation of [`wcscpy_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s) states that the debug version of this function fills the destination buffer with the special value `0xFE`.

When you call `wcscpy_s(tmp, sizeof(tmp), defaultVal);` you pass the size of the `tmp` buffer, but `wcscpy_s` wants the length in number of characters. Therefore the length you pass to `wcscpy_s` is twice as long as it should be, and as the `tmp` buffer is overwritten by `0xfe` you get a buffer overflow and undefined behaviour, even if the length if the source string (`L"Default";`) is small.

So use [`_countof(tmp)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro) instead of [`_sizeof(tmp)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/sizeof-operator).

This said, I suggest you learn how to use the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained in Michael Walz's answer, you have a buffer overflow caused by passing an incorrect buffer size.

In addition to his suggestion of using `_countof(tmp)` instead of `sizeof(tmp)`, I'd like to add that in **C++** there's a convenient overload of [wcscpy_s() that *automatically* deduces the correct buffer size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx):

> ```
> template <size_t size>  
> errno_t wcscpy_s(  
>    wchar_t (&strDestination)[size],  
>    const wchar_t *strSource   
> ); // C++ only
> ```

Basically, you can write *simpler* code like this, that will just work:

```
wchar_t tmp[100];

// Use the C++-only template overload of wcscpy_s
// that automatically deduces the destination buffer size
auto result = wcscpy_s(tmp, defaultVal);
```

If you use this overload, you are immune to those `sizeof`/`_countof` mismatch kind of bugs.

Note that this C++ overload works only if you have a static buffer like your `wchar_t tmp[100]`, as the C++ compiler must be able to figure out the buffer size at *compile-time*. On the other hand, when you have *pointers* to *dynamically*-allocated buffers, you have to pass the correct buffer size explicitly.